# A valuation question about the proof of Löwenheim–Skolem theorem.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#:%7E:text=It%20implies%20that%20if%20a%20countable%20first%2Dorder%20theory%20has%20an%20infinite%20model%2C%20then%20for%20every%20infinite%20cardinal%20number%20%CE%BA%20it%20has%20a%20model%20of%20size%20%CE%BA%2C%20and%20that%20no%20first%2Dorder%20theory%20with%20an%20infinite%20model%20can%20have%20a%20unique%20model%20up%20to%20isomorphism.) of Löwenheim–Skolem theorem, there is such a valuation in the proof of the downward part:

> $|N|=\kappa$

From $\left\vert F(A) \right\vert \leq \left\vert A \right\vert + \left\vert \sigma \right\vert + \aleph_0 \,$, we can get $\left\vert F^n(A) \right\vert \leq \left\vert A \right\vert + n\left\vert \sigma \right\vert + n\aleph_0 \,,$ for $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Expanding $F^\omega(A)$ as $\bigcup_{m\in \omega}F^m(A)$, we know that $|N|\leq |A| + \aleph_0 \cdot |\sigma|$. But how can we get that $|N|=\kappa$?

Postscript: the full sketch of the proof (of the downward part) in wiki:

> For each first-order $\sigma \,$-formula $\varphi(y,x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) \,,$ the axiom of choice implies the existence of a function
> $f_{\varphi}: M^n\to M$ such that, for all $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in M$, either $M\models\varphi(f_{\varphi} (a_1, \dots, a_n), a_1, \dots, a_n)$ or $M\models\neg\exists y \varphi(y, a_1, \dots, a_n) \,.$
>
> Applying the axiom of choice again we get a function from the first
> order formulas $\varphi$ to such functions $f_{\varphi} \,.$
>
> The family of functions $f_{\varphi}$ gives rise to a preclosure
> operator $F \,$ on the power set of $M \,$ $F(A) = \{b \in M \mid b = f_{\varphi}(a_1, \dots, a_n); \, \varphi \in \sigma ; \, a_1, \dots, a_n \in A \}$
>
> for $A \subseteq M \,.$
>
> Iterating $F \,$ countably many times results in a closure operator
> $F^{\omega} \,.$ Taking an arbitrary subset $A \subseteq M$ such that
> $\left\vert A \right\vert = \kappa$, and having defined $N = F^{\omega}(A) \,,$ one can see that also $\left\vert N \right\vert = \kappa \,.$ $N \,$ is an elementary substructure of $M \,$ by the Tarski–Vaught test.
>
> The trick used in this proof is essentially due to Skolem, who introduced function symbols for the Skolem functions $f_{\varphi}$ into the language. One could also define the $f_{\varphi}$ as partial functions such that $f_{\varphi}$ is defined if and only if $M \models \exists y \varphi(y,a_1,\dots,a_n) \,.$ The only important point is that $F \,$ is a preclosure operator such that $F(A) \,$ contains a solution for every formula with parameters in $A \,$ which has a solution in $M \,$ and that
> $\left\vert F(A) \right\vert \leq \left\vert A \right\vert + \left\vert \sigma \right\vert + \aleph_0 \,.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal with $\kappa\geq |\sigma|$, and $|A| = \kappa$, right?

Since $A\subseteq N$, $\kappa \leq |N|$. On the other hand, $|N|\leq |A|+\aleph_0\cdot |\sigma| = \max(\kappa,\aleph_0,|\sigma|) = \kappa$.